# Call external file from XSL

Tags: sql-server, xslt, call

Can we call an external file (xml, Excel or text file) from XSL?

How do I call SQL Server stored procedures through XSL?

All I am trying to figure out is a way to do mappings from source XML to target XML (let's say if the value of mode vehicle is X in the source, I need to translate it to Y in translate XML based on the mapping stored either in an external file or through a SQL Server stored procedure).

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 1 has the `document` function (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#document) to pull in additional XML documents. Beyond that in XSLT 1 you need to look at extension scripts or elements to deal with other sources, such ways depend on the XSLT processor and/or the programming language or platform (e.g. Java or .NET) it is implemented in.

XSLT 2 in addition to the `document` function has the `doc` function for dealing with XML input, it has the `unparsed-text` function (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-unparsed-text) for text formats and `collection` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-collection) for input collections. As for SQL, as Saxon 9 on Java is probably the XSLT 2 processor used most, it has in its commercial editions an SQL extension http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/sql-extension/.

XSLT 3 adds support for JSON with functions like `parse-json` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-parse-json) or `json-doc` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-json-doc) or `json-to-xml` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-json-to-xml).

In general I wonder why you need XSLT plus a custom mapping format as in my view template based XSLT in the form

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <bar>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </bar>
</xsl:template>
```

is the way to declare and implement the mapping. However, if you have a custom mapping, then in all versions of XSLT you can use it create XSLT with XSLT and then run the created XSLT to execute the mapping.